# Changing the address of the opener window in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, popup, browser

From a child popup window (opened using window.open), I am trying to change the URL of the window that opened me, e.g.

window.opener.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

In all browsers this works wonderfully, except for IE8 (and I am somewhat sure it worked in previous IE8. Maybe a security update kills this).

In IE8 what happens is that the line above is treated as a request to open a NEW window with the address and the original opener window stays the same. And, since I am not putting this line inside an onclick event, this is treated as a popup.

So how do I do this in IE8? How do I change the opener location?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is *just not possible*. I got no answer from anybody and all my research indicated that this is just another way MS added to block popups.

Answer (score 1):

try to move action into parent window, like this:

```
//parent.htm
function changeUrl(url) {
  location.href = url;
  window.reload();
}

window.open("child.htm");

.....

//child.htm
window.opener.changeUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
on the opener window define a function called goto ;-)

```
function goto(url){ window.location.href = url; }
```

now from the child window call `window.opener.goto(url);`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the opener window (it's bestbuy,com and other retailers), and even if I had, they are in a different domain than myself, so I believe I can't call any method in the opener window.